# Kie oni povus legi la originalan Kumeŭaŭa-n en Esperanto?

Tags: culture

La libro estas verkita de Tibor Sekelj. Mi ĵus legis la Ĉinan version, kiun mi tre ŝatas. Kaj mi volas serĉi la Esperantan version.

Answer (score 4):

You can get it [here](http://esperanto-usa.org/retbutiko/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=1006_1009&products_id=9460&zenid=TZ5oUdO4,kI7x8gO61HET2), for example.
Vi povas aĉeti ĝin [ĉi tie](http://esperanto-usa.org/retbutiko/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=1006_1009&products_id=9460&zenid=TZ5oUdO4,kI7x8gO61HET2).

Currently also as a paperback on [amazon.com](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9063360185).

Comment: Ĉu estas elektronika versio?

Comment: Mi pensas gxi estas papera libro. Mi ne povas trovi elektronikan version.

Comment: Kaj akirebla en la Retbutiko: http://www.retbutiko.net/eo/ero/kume